# LSI RAID6 with 3 disks loss recovery

Tags: raid, hard-drive, cache, lsi, failed

My hardware RAID6 on an LSI controller experienced a disaster - 3 disks were physically removed from it - they are not faulty. After reboot the 3 drives were showing as "Unconfigured BAD". I used another identical controller to check the disk configuration and to retain the cache data on the original controller. However, the configuration from the disks loaded into the controller and the rebuild on the firstly removed disks started. So the RAID was rebuilt into the state when the 3-rd HDD was removed. Now the only thing is missing to complete the miracle of RAID resurrection - to apply the data from the cache from the original controller. And here is the question - how to do this? Is it even possible?
The support communication has been not really helpful - the only thing I got from them was that they wanted logs and afterwards I'm waiting with questions on status update for almost two days so I'm asking the common brains.

Comment: Why did you use another controller? What you was trying to accomplish? Please give us some more context.

Comment: The idea for another controller was to prevent the data in cache. I wanted to load the configuration from the disks and preview it to get the idea of how badly the RAID has been damaged. I expected I will have to clear the controller configuration including the cache so I used a controller that has nothing valuable there. I didn't expect the configuration to be imported automatically and I did definitely not expect the rebuild to be started automatically as well. But this is probably the best scenario possible assuming the disaster the RAID encountered.